# Status bar and overlay

Tags: android

I'm showing a custom overlay with this parameter inflating the view from a service:

```
params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(WindowManager
        .LayoutParams
        .MATCH_PARENT,
        statusBarHeight, WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY, WindowManager
        .LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN
        | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE | WindowManager.LayoutParams
        .FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE, 0);
params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER | Gravity.TOP;
```

The problem is that if the status bar is expanded, the overlay is over the quick settings menu. How can I avoid that? I'm using android 6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of **TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY** use **TYPE_SYSTEM_ERROR**.

```
params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            100,
            // Allows the view to be on top of the StatusBar
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ERROR,
            // Keeps the button presses from going to the background window
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE |
            // Enables the notification to recieve touch events
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL |
            // Draws over status bar
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

params.gravity =  Gravity.TOP|Gravity.CENTER;      

mWindowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
mWindowManager.addView(mView, mLP);
```

This should solve your issue.

Comment: I had to remove not touchable flag as you wrote in addition.